# What's the bare minimum permission set for Sql Server 2005 services?

Tags: sql-server-2005, security, system-administration

Best practices recommend not installing Sql Server to run as SYSTEM.  What is the bare minumum you need to give the user account you create for it?

Comment: You may want to retag this to use sql2005 which seems to be more common than sqlserver2005 and sysadmin which is more common than system-administration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, SQL Server 2005 installation will create a security group called SQLServer2005MSSQLUser$ComputerName$MSSQLSERVER with the correct rights. You just need to create a domain user or local user and make it a member of that group.

More details are available in the SQL Server Books Online: [Reviewing Windows NT Rights and Privileges Granted for SQL Server Service Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504(SQL.90).aspx#Review_NT_rights)

Answer (score 1):

Typically I create a Domain User with only the specific rights on the network which I will require the server to have (i.e. to write to the network backup drive), I then add the account to local power users or local administrators depending on what needs to be done on the machine, however this isn't required.  I've installed SQL a number of times using a standard user as a Service Account but you need to ensure that the user has access to write to the resources as listed at https://web.archive.org/web/20081223155956/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283811 .  Its probably not as defined an answer as you wanted but I'm only a developer (not a professional DBA / System Engineer).

Mauro
PS dont downmark me for saying "only a developer" :P